# What does $\det f'(a)=0$ tell us about the function $f$ at $a$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, soft-question, determinant

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a function differentiable at $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$.  The property that $\det f'(a)\ne 0$ is relevant in multiple theorems e.g. the Inverse Function Theorem, yet I have trouble building an intuition of what such property tells us about $f$ at $a$.

There is, of course, the geometric interpretation of determinants as signed volume, and thus  one could say that "$\det f'(a)= 0$ tells us that $f'(a)$ i.e. the (best) linear approximation of the function
$$\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n : h \mapsto \Big[f(a+h)-f(a)\Big]$$
'compresses' any $n$-dimensional shape into a shape of lower dimension." By itself, such explanation does not give me much of a geometric intuition of the behavior of $f$ around $a$, and thus I was wondering if anyone could add something to the story.

$$\textbf{What does $\det f'(a)=0$ tell us about the function $f$ at $a$?}$$

$$\textbf{Is there another geometric intuition corresponding to $\det f'(a)=0$?}$$

Comment: Critical points. Saddles, inflections, turning points, ...

Answer (score 3):

The total derivative $A=f'(a)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ which is the best linear approximation to $f$ at $a$, i.e. if given some small vector $x$, $f(a+x) \simeq f(a) + Ax$, it tells you how $f$ transforms vectors in a neighborhood of $a$. Are they scaled? Are they rotated? Are they "flattened"? etc.

If $\det A=0$ then this tells you that the linear map is singular, i.e. that there are vectors $x$ for which $Ax = 0$, equivalently that $A$ fails to be injective, i.e. there are vectors $u, v, u\neq v$ so that $Au = Av$. Intuitively maybe you can think that near $a$ there is some direction $x$ along which $f$ is locally constant.

This is trouble for things like the Inverse Function Theorem, because if you want to construct an inverse, even a local inverse, you're going to need to assign a unique $x$ to each $y$ in the image of $f$ near $f(a)$, but if $f'(a)$ is singular then you can't do that.

Comment: the one exception I can think of where having zero determinant can still provide somewhat meaningful/systematic information is in the special case where the map in question has constant rank (a commonly encountered situation when dealing with Lie group homomorphisms, or equivariant maps with a transitive action on the domain), because in this case, the constant rank-theorem comes to the rescue and tells us how the map looks like locally. If the rank starts jumping, then of course we’re likely going to have to do a case-by-case analysis of each function.